# Como mostrar a versão da compilação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Vejo em algumas páginas e sistemas a versão de compilação.

Gostaria de mostrar em uma *view* a versão da compilação do meu projeto em ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é só isto que você quer:

```
@typeof(SeuNamespace.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetVersion.cs).